# For Linux device driver programming, why I can use APIs like `sysfs_create_group` without `linux/sysfs.h` header?

Tags: c, linux, embedded, linux-device-driver, sysfs

When I compiled a device driver with APIs like `sysfs_create_group` or attributes declaration without including `linux/sysfs.h`, I found that the driver can still be compiled, and the driver worked fine with the device. Furthermore, I had searched other headers included in the driver, such as `linux/module.h`, `linux/i2c.h`, or `linux/device.h`, none of them includes `linux/sysfs.h`.

I assume the APIs are exported by the kernel, so the loaded driver is able to call the function. In that case, is it okay not to include `linux/sysfs.h`? or is it caused by other reasons?

I have just begun to learn C and device driver programming recently, so the question might be unclear.

The Linux kernel version I used is 5.15.

Comment: One of your include files will be including `linux/sysfs.h`. Possibly indirectly, i.e. it includes a file, which includes a file, which includes sysfs.h. Possibly nested even deeper than that. Compile your code with the `-E` option to see the pre-processed output. That should show you where the include came from.

Comment: Thank you, pmacfarlane! I have checked the `*.i` file, and `linux/sysfs.h` was included. However, does that mean I don't need to include `linux/sysfs.h` in the driver? or is it better to include it?

Comment: If you explicitly use things from that header file, you should include it, just to be sure. (Maybe in the future, one of those other files will stop including it, and your driver will break.)

Answer (score 1):

One of your include files will be including `linux/sysfs.h`, possibly indirectly, i.e. it includes a file, which includes a file, which includes sysfs.h. Possibly nested even deeper than that. You could compile your code with the -E option to gcc to see the pre-processed output. That should show you where the include came from.

Relying on other header files to `#include` files that are required to build your code is fragile and not recommended, especially if you don't even know which one it is. Maybe in the future you won't #include whichever one happened to bring in sysfs.h, and then your code won't compile. Or maybe a future version of that header file won't include sysfs.h.

If your code explicitly uses something provided by a header file, you should `#include` it yourself.

Comment: While the last paragraph I'm totally agree with, the previous ones may be improved by explainig how `make includecheck` works in the Linux kernel project.